# mysql LEFT JOIN main table and two additional tables with max value from each

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have three tables:

```
Users
+-------+-----+----+
| id    | val1|val2|
+-------+-----+----+
| 1     |  1  |3   |
| 2     |  2  |5   |
| 3     |  4  |7   |
+-------+-----+----+

UsersData
+----+--------------+------------+-----|
| id | users_id     | created_at | gold|
+----+--------------+------------+-----|
|  9 |  1           |121454561212| 14  |
|  10|  1           |131454561212|  2  |
|  11|  2           |111454561212| 99  |
+----+--------------+------------+-----+

Extra
+----+------------+-----|
| id | users_id   | val4|
+----+------------+-----|
|  1 |  1         |  5  |
|  2 |  1         |  6  |
|  3 |  1         |  7  |
+----+------------+-----+
```

So what i wish to achieve(in a single query) is to get a single row result for user with id = 1, that holds:

- everything from Users Table
- gold value of the most recent entry for that user (users_id = 1, created_at = MAX)
- biggest val4 from the Extra table, where users_id = 1

So the result row would look like this:

```
+-------+-----+----+-----+----+
| id    | val1|val2|gold |val4|
+-------+-----+----+-----+----|
| 1     |  1  |3   | 2   |  7 |
------------------------------+
```

I can get The first part done with

```
SELECT Users.id, Users.val1, Users.val2, UsersData.gold
FROM UsersData
LEFT JOIN Users ON UsersData.users_id = Users.id
WHERE Users.id = 1 
ORDER BY UsersData.created_at DESC
LIMIT 1
```

and the second part with

```
SELECT MAX(Distances.distance) AS maxdistance FROM Distances WHERE Distances.users_id = 1
```

But i can't combine them no matter how i try... I would really like to have this done in single query, obviously i can do it with multiple - but i believe it is just my lack of mysql skills that is the issue here.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post up a sqlfiddle/dbfiddle/rextester of same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use subquery:

```
SELECT Users.id, Users.val1, Users.val2, UsersData.gold,
(SELECT MAX(Distances.distance) FROM Distances WHERE Distances.users_id = Users.id) AS maxdistance
FROM UsersData
RIGHT JOIN Users ON UsersData.users_id = Users.id
WHERE Users.id = 1 
ORDER BY UsersData.created_at DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This is subquery connected by Users.id:

```
SELECT MAX(Distances.distance) FROM Distances WHERE Distances.users_id = Users.id) AS maxdistance
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use subqueries like this:

```
select u.*,
       (select ud.gold
        from userdata ud
        where ud.users_id = u.id
        order by ud.created_at desc
        limit 1
       ) as most_recent_gold,
       (select max(e.val4)
        from extra e
        where e.users_id = u.id
       ) as max_val4
from users u
where u.id = 1 ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution - it works, but i was wondering if there is any benefit of not using the right join as in the accepted answer used?

Comment: @siamon . . . You mention three tables in your question.  This answer gets information from all three tables.  The other answer doesn't even reference all three.